# Deleting items from a UICollection but getting an "Array index out of range" error

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, uicollectionview

I'm using Parse as a backend and loading items into a UICollectionView. Everything works great but I can't seem to properly delete certain ranges of items.
Here's my delete function:

```
func deleteButtonTapped() {
  let indexPaths = collectionView!.indexPathsForSelectedItems()!

  self.collectionView!.performBatchUpdates({
    for index in indexPaths {
      self.tasks[index.item].deleteInBackground()
      self.tasks.removeAtIndex(index.item)
    }
  }, completion: nil)

  self.collectionView!.deleteItemsAtIndexPaths(indexPaths)
}
```

I get the error: fatal error: Array index out of range
I think this is because as the for loop cycles it loses an item but maintains the original count. I checked to make sure self.tasks and indexPaths returns what I expect. Not sure what else to try.
How can I refactor this? Any help or direction would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try to put the  `self.collectionView!.deleteItemsAtIndexPaths(indexPaths)` inside the completion handler of `performBatchUpdates`.

**EDIT**

It looks like you are attempting to remove an item from self.tasks while accessing it. Say for example your tasks have 5 items [A,B,C,D,E] and you select to delete D & E. on the first iteration you delete item at index 3 (i.e D). Now tasks have 4 items [A,B,C,E]. On the next iteration when you try to access item at index 4, which before the previous delete pointed to E, you'll get index out of bound error.

Comment: Unfortunately, I get the same error. The error actually happens inside of the for loop so it never makes it that far.